# Find a minimum Column value in pivot table

Tags: laravel, performance, eloquent

I have two Models. `Product` and `Vendor`. these models have Many to Many relation.
the pivot table have Extra Columns beside `product_id` and `vendor_id`, `price and off_price` so the table Columns are like these:

| product_id | vendor_id | price | off_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

I wrote custom attribute in my `Product` model:

```php
    protected $appends = [
        'cheapest_vendor'
    ];

    protected function CheapestVendor(): Attribute
    {
        $price = $this->belongsToMany(Vendor::class)->min('price');
        $vendor = $this->belongsToMany(Vendor::class)->where('price', '=', $price)->first();
        return new Attribute(
            get: fn () => ['price' => $price, 'vendor' => $vendor],
        );
    }
```

In my blade file I Call

```php
  $product->cheapest_vendor->price and $product->cheapest_vendor->vendor->name
```

multiple times. the problem is I have so many duplicate query on that blade page because of that.
I do understand every time I call `cheapest_vendor` attribute , I actually run 2 queries but I can't think the other way to do this.
I need a way to find minimum price on the pivot table and the vendor of that product without so many duplicate query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is definitely having both `$price = $this->belongsToMany(Vendor::class)` and `$vendor = $this->belongsToMany(Vendor::class)` inside of your Attribute method. If you define them there, there isn't a way to check if that Relationship has been loaded, so you'll call 2 Queries every time you access `$product->cheapest_vendor`.

You *can* accomplish this with a single Relationship to `vendors`:

```php
public function vendors() {
  return $this->belongsToMany(Vendor::class)
  ->withPivot(['price', 'off_price']);
}
```

The next step is a 2-parter:

1. Make sure your Attribute checks for the loaded Relationship and uses it if defined, or loads it:

```php
protected function CheapestVendor(): Attribute {
  if ($this->relationLoaded('vendors') {
    $this->load('vendors', function ($subQuery) {
      return $subQuery->orderBy('price', 'ASC');
    });
  }

  $cheapestVendor = $this->vendors->first();

  return new Attribute(
    get: fn () => ['price' => $cheapestVendor->price, 'vendor' => $cheapestVendor],
  );
}
```

For a single Model, this works great. You can do this:

```php
// In your Controller: 
$product = Product::first();

// In your View:
{{ $product->cheapest_vendor->price }}

{{ $product->cheapest_vendor->vendor->name }}
```

And only a single extra query will be called.

2. For multiple Models, ensure you Eager Load the relationship correctly before continuing:

```php
$products = Product::with(['vendors' => function ($subQuery) { 
  return $subQuery->orderBy('price', 'ASC');
})->get();
```

Now, when looping these Products and displaying their `cheapest_vendor` Attribute, no additional queries will be executed:

```php
@foreach($products as $product)
  {{ $product->cheapest_vendor->price }}
  {{ $product->cheapest_vendor->vendor->name }}
@endforeach
```

---

If it is easier to have 2 Relationships, 1 to `vendors` and one to `cheapest_vendors`, you can do that too:

```php
public function vendors() {
  return $this->belongsToMany(Vendor::class)
  ->withPivot(['price', 'off_price']);
}

public function cheapest_vendors() {
  return $this->belongsToMany(Vendor::class, 'vendor_id')
  ->withPivot(['price', 'off_price'])
  ->orderBy('price', 'ASC');
}
```

*Note: This still needs to be a `belongsToMany()`, as they are connected via a `pivot` table*

Now, you can simplify your logic:

```php
protected function CheapestVendor(): Attribute {
  if ($this->relationLoaded('cheapest_vendors') {
    $this->load('cheapest_vendors');
  }

  $cheapestVendor = $this->cheapest_vendors->first();

  return new Attribute(
    get: fn () => ['price' => $cheapestVendor->price, 'vendor' => $cheapestVendor],
  );
}
```

And in your Controller when loading `$product` (or `$products`):

```php
$product = Product::with('cheapest_vendors')->first();

// OR

$products = Product::with('cheapest_vendors')->get();
```

When accessing `$product->cheapest_vendor->price` (and `->vendor->name`), no additional queries will be executed. This will also let you access `->vendors`, which would return all associated vendors, vs the single relationship method where `->vendors` would only include a Collection of a Single `Vendor` Model instance.

Comment: thank you, I got the concept that I need and the solution works perfectly. ❤️

Comment: price returned a null in CheapestVendor method , so I change the code to this and it works: ``` $cheapestVendor = $this->cheapest_vendors()->withPivot('price','off_price')->get(['price'])->first();  ```

Comment: `->cheapest_vendors()` with `()` will execute a new query each time. You should add that `->withPivot(['price', 'off_price'])` to your relationship, then use `$this->cheapest_vendors->first()` (`->get(['price'])->first()` is also unnecessary, as you can simply do `$this->cheapest_vendors->first()->price` to accomplish the same thing)